# Change listbox options dynamically, on click of some event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<x:select id="FileType" width="210px">
        <x:option value="JPG">JPG</x:option>
        <x:option value="PNG">PNG</x:option>
        <x:option value="PDF">PDF</x:option>
        <x:option value="TIF">TIF</x:option>
        <x:option value="BMP">BMP</x:option>
</x:select>
```

Now on click of some button I want to change its option for this am doing like it.

```
function fun(){
    $("#FileType").outerHTML = '<x:select  name="FileType" id="FileType"><x:option selected="true" value="JPG">JPG</x:option><x:option value="PNG">PNG</x:option><x:option value="PDF">PDF</x:option><x:option value="TIF">TIF</x:option><x:option value="BMP">BMP</x:option></x:select>';
}
```

But `$("#FileType").outerHTML` is not working , if I alert `($("#FileType").outerHTML)` it's giving me `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
function fun(){
    $("#FileType").outerHTML = '<x:select  name="FileType" id="FileType"><x:option selected="true" value="JPG">JPG</x:option><x:option value="PNG">PNG</x:option><x:option value="PDF">PDF</x:option><x:option value="TIF">TIF</x:option><x:option value="BMP">BMP</x:option></x:select>';
}
```

Try this:

```
function fun(){
    $("#FileType")[0].outerHTML = '<x:select  name="FileType" id="FileType"><x:option selected="true" value="JPG">JPG</x:option><x:option value="PNG">PNG</x:option><x:option value="PDF">PDF</x:option><x:option value="TIF">TIF</x:option><x:option value="BMP">BMP</x:option></x:select>';
}
```

Note the `[0]` after the selector to specify the first element found.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/k4Pb7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not have an outerHTML method, so you are trying to call a DOM method on a jQuery collection - which is why you are getting an undefined result.

You need to do something along the lines of `$("#FileType").parent().html()`, `$("#FileType").replaceWith()` or `$("#FileType").get(0).outerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function fun(){
    $("#FileType option").remove();
    $("#FileType").append('<option selected="true" value="JPG">JPG</option><option value="PNG">PNG</option><option value="PDF">PDF</option><option value="TIF">TIF</option><option value="BMP">BMP</option>');
}
```